# How to make image gallery centered

Tags: html, css

I need help in centering my image gallery, i cant make it to work how i want, gutters are being pain in the ass and so are calculating margins and widths. I want images centered, so three images per row, with one image being all the way to the left, second image being centered and third image being all the way to the right, using margins and padding with floats individually I believe is a bad practice, there has to be a better way to do this. Each image is 295px width I changed their widths in photoshop. I don't wish to use css grid, flexbox etc… I just want to do it in basic way with floats and box model. If there is any good way to center these images with some space in between them.

[image]

```css
/* CSS Document */


/*body {
 margin: 20px 250px;
}*/

#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

header {
  background-image: url("../Images/view2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

header #navbar {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#navbar a {
  padding: 30px 35px;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  background: rgba(211, 204, 38, 1.00);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

main #page {
  text-align: center;
}

main #inner-content ul {
  list-style: none;
}

main #inner-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 17.7px;
}

main #inner-content #block1 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
}

main #inner-content #block2 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
}

main #inner-content #block3 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
}

main #inner-content #block1 li {
  margin-left: 12.5px;
}

main #inner-content #block2 li {
  margin-left: 12.5px;
}

main #inner-content #block3 li {
  margin-left: 12.5px;
}

#about-text {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background: rgba(96, 96, 96, 1.00);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: left;
}

footer #contact {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

footer #form {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <header id="header">
    <h1>ISMAR PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
      <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>

    <p id="about-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil error aspernatur vitae illo animi aliquam perferendis dicta, temporibus, dolores suscipit accusantium cumque voluptas nesciunt pariatur numquam omnis quo sunt minus voluptatum vero odio
      ipsam mollitia. Itaque consequatur non harum molestias quibusdam voluptatem provident, eius, aliquam magnam, nesciunt ipsum est maiores! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed beatae veritatis provident expedita facere dolore
      saepe autem cupiditate voluptas assumenda enim odit illum et placeat amet officiis, accusamus adipisci veniam, hic. Velit fugiat vitae, laboriosam omnis voluptates rem, totam esse quisquam sunt hic voluptatum amet quam repudiandae sequi incidunt
      nam!</p>

    <p id="page">01</p>

    <div id="inner-content">

      <ul id="block1">
        <li><img src="Images/nature.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="Images/panorama.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="Images/self.jpg"></li>
      </ul>


      <ul id="block2">
        <li><img src="Images/self2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="Images/sky.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="Images/telex.jpg"></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="block3">
        <li><img src="Images/urban-beatz.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="Images/urban-beatz2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="Images/view.jpg"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </main>

  <footer>
    <div id="contact">
      <h2>CONTACT ME</h2>
      <p>randomemail@gmail.com</p>
      <p>+456 34 55 5567</p>
    </div>


    <form action="#" name="form" id="form">
      <label for="name">Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="name"><br>
      <label for="last-name">Last name</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="last-name"><br>
      <label for="email">Email</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="email"><br>
      <label for="message">Message</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="message"><br>
    </form>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: `i believe is a bad practice, there has to be a better way to do this` -- well yes, but then you go on to say you don't want to use any of the better ways to do this. Using flex layout would do this trivially.

Comment: *The first rule of centering is **don't use `float`**.*

Comment: _"I dont wish to use css grid, flexbox etc… i just want to do it in basic way with floats and box model"_ translates to, _"I don't want to learn anything new and stick with the old ways."_

Comment: @hungerstar, while I mostly agree with you, there's also something to be said against including 47 libraries for minimal use of the libraries. And, yes, I've seen things like this, because "if it can be done with a library, it should" mentality.

Comment: Edited my answer to add an alternate way using floats

Comment: @computercarguy for a simple gallery like this it's a far stretch to suggest that the alternative to not using floats is implementing multiple libraries (heck even one library for that matter). You don't need a library to use flexbox or css grid. If a large majority of your potential audience is not using browsers that support those features, that's a completely different story and is not outlined by the OP.

Comment: @hungerstar, it's not that I'm advocating against libraries, I'm advocating for making sure you really need a library before you include it. A gallery like this would probably be a good use for a library, since it's almost guaranteed to expand scope and need ever more of the gallery library in the future.

Comment: Possibly, but the whole library discussion for this topic is completely out of left field. It's like me mentioning you don't need a CMS to do this. Unnecessary and adds noise to the discussion.

Comment: Grid layout and flex layout aren't libraries -- I mean they could be if you wanted to use a library, but they're part of CSS3 with broad browser support according to caniuse. Nobody's mentioned libraries or jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you don't want to use grid or flexbox, then I'd suggest the old school table is a good option.

```css
.my-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.my-table td {
  /* Change this padding to add gutters of desirable size*/
  padding: 20px;
}

.my-table img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="image_1_location.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img src="image_2_location.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img src="image_3_location.jpg" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="image_4_location.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img src="image_5_location.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img src="image_6_location.jpg" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Option 2**

There is another way you can achieve this with floats if you want.

The only thing is that you'll have to make multiple containers to accommodate for the floats.

Here's how you can do it

```css
.my-image-gallery {
  position: relative;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.floating-element {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.image-container {
  padding: 10px;
}

.image-container>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-image-gallery">
  <div id="row-1" class="clearfix">
    <!-- You'll need to make a container for each image -->
    <div class="floating-element">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="google-logo.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="floating-element">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="google-logo.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="floating-element">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="google-logo.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML. Also, using a table is not a good option.

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I don't use add it too. But my editor "prettifies" everything. :)

Comment: Not sure if tables for layout is a great idea.

Comment: @Rob I've had to author some XSL lately, and now, I need the closing slash! Grrrrr!

Comment: @hungerstar I understand that it is not the modern way of doing things and quite complex to write properly too, but it is still one of the oldest and reliable way to place content. If your application is trivial, like in the case of this question, then I don't see an issue in using tables for some part of your html.

Comment: Not using tables isn't a _"modern"_ practice. Tables for layouts has always been a bad practice. Just because tables were widely used for layout at one point doesn't change that or justify their use in this situation. People also used absolute positioning for every element on their site or sliced up images instead of writing HTML/CSS, should we still encourage those practices because they are reliable, simple, and once widely used?

Comment: So your argument is that more people used to use it so it is bad to use it now in certain parts of your html? Again I'm all in for good practices, but at the same time if a solution works for you and it is manageable in a longer run (even if it is placing absolute containers everywhere), then we should not demerit its application.

Comment: The purpose of the table element is for tabular data not layout. Using table for layout causes issues for flexibility in said layout, traversing the DOM using javascript, and search engines trying to wade through it since tables don't follow the flow. Among even more reasons, tables used for layout means they are not being used for their semantic meaning. These are technical reasons and not "just because".

Comment: @Aditya that is not my argument at all. Regardless of how popular the previously mentioned practices were, they were and will continue to be poor practices for site layout. Don't confuse that with _"never use"_ tables or _"never use absolute positioning."_ Which seems to happen a lot with those that have the methodology of _"if it gets the job done, meh."_

Comment: @Rob fair points and I agree with them all. As I said in an earlier comment, I am all in for proper way of doing things. There are standards for a reason. But if there are limited choices as to which tools or solutions you can use, as in case with the question (whatever personal or professional reasons be), then as a developer, you should know to work your way around things.

Comment: @hungerstar Trust me, I'm with you too. I'd never go for something that just gets the job done. But just for this specific question, it is clear that the author at least knows about the flexbox and grids and/or other more sophisticated layouts, but they don't want to use it. But everyone is just trying to steer them to do something they feel comfortable with. What I'm trying to do is just be helpful in given restrictions of choices (personal or professional).

Comment: And I gave the OP a floats example, but it will be a cold day in hell if I proved a table based version (lol).

Comment: Shoot I think I came up with a work around, I personally would never use it but it does fit the criteria lol

Comment: @hungerstar Look man, I don't wanna argue anymore. Rob is being empirical and concise with his explanations but you are just being dramatic at this point.

Comment: @Aditya lol, you're being dramatic. I wasn't even arguing with my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

While I think this is a riduculous way of doing this. You can use `calc()` to add a margin on both sides of the center `img` this example is using your current markup with no flex:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 calc(50% - 408px);
}
li {
  width: 259px;
  height: 259px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/0f78ksvx/12/

The better way that you don't want to do would be to use flex:

```
#block1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/0f78ksvx/3/

Answer (score 0):

Below are some minimal examples of how to implement your gallery. The concept is the same for both the Flexbox and Float approaches. Tell each image that it should be 1/3 the width of the container element (including margin) and allow the images to wrap inside their container element.

The `overflow` and negative margin properties used in both *"remove"* the outermost margins and may not be something that you desire or are concerned with.

**Using Flexbox**

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin: -1rem;
  background-color: rgba( 111, 222, 50, 0.15);
}

.gallery img {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: calc( 33.33333% - 2rem );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/fc0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/d10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/d10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/fc0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/d10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/fc0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using Floats**

I **highly** recommend moving away from floats and using Flexbox or CSS Grid unless there is a specific behavior that floats provide that favors some requirement.

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery {
  margin: -1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba( 111, 222, 50, 0.15 ); /* For illustrative purposes. */
}

.gallery img {
  float: left;
  margin: 1rem;
  max-width: calc( 33.33333% - 2rem); /* Subtract left and right margins */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/fc0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/d10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/d10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/fc0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/d10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/fc0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery {
  overflow: hidden; /* For illustrative purposes. */
  background-color: rgba( 111, 222, 50, 0.15 ); /* For illustrative purposes. */
}

.gallery img {
  float: left;
  margin: 1rem;
  max-width: calc( 33.33333% - 2rem); /* Subtract left and right margins */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/fc0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/d10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/d10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/fc0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/d10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/fc0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use the html

```
<center>
    image code here
</center>

<right>
```

and

```
<left>
```

Comment: This tag has been deprecated. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: Ok. I found this css version here from a google search: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center_website.asp - it may be a good starting point

Comment: @computercarguy Worse. The `<center>` element is obsolete. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: There is no such thing as a  `<right>` or `<left>` tag.